# Apply CSS rule only on computer screens, not on mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a logo in my header that's too small. I found this piece of code where I can increase the size but I only want it to apply to computer screens and not to mobile or tablet. The code is:

```
.site-title img   {max-width:100%; height:auto}
.site-description {display:none}
```

I want to change the `100%` to `200%` but only on computer screens.

Can somebody tell me which code makes that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsive Web Design, using media-queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    // this css will only be used when the screen size is min 800px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are used to apply CSS rules to only matching devices. Specify a `max-width` or `min-width` to apply the style rules to.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    body {
        background-color: skyblue;
    }
}
```